# Dante Socks5 proxy server doesn't restart

Tags: ubuntu, dante

I have installed danted service which was working fine but stopped now and its not restarting now I am getting following errors

```
 danted.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: /run/systemd/unit-root/opt: No such file or directory
 danted.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /bin/sh: No such file or directory

 Failed to start SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted).
```

Also tried reinstalling but same error

Please help

Thanks in advance.